# 'globalThis' is not defined

Tags: reactjs

this my code

```
const Darko = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [logout, { loading, error }] = useMutation(LOGOUT, {
    onCompleted: () => {
      history.push("/");
      globalThis.location.reload();
    },
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
  });
  return <div>...</div>}
```

Why am I getting an error 'globalThis' is not defined

Comment: Is this in nodejs or browser?

Comment: globalThis is not a defined variable.

Comment: @RRR I am using react Hence browser.

Comment: Have you checked if the variable is available outside arrow function, I think just like 'this', globalThis also is not available inside arrow function.